# Google My Business Insights api using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, google-my-business-api

I need to use google my business insights data through api. I am using asp.net core c#, i am using service 
account. I would appriciate if anyone could provide me the code using c#. Check the image which data I need to  fetch .

[image]

Comment: stackoverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service

Comment: Check their API Documents, how to integrate it with C#/.NET

Comment: There is no clear documentation @sh